# Maintaining a TCP Connection in an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, android-asynctask

I'm using an AsyncTask to establish a TCP Connection and sending/receiving data through it.

My current Code looks like this at the moment:

```
public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Boolean> {
    Socket nsocket; //Network Socket
    InputStream nis; //Network Input Stream
    OutputStream nos; //Network Output Stream
    boolean bSocketStarted = false;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) { //This runs on a different thread
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            // Connect to address
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: Creating socket");
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("google.de", 80);
            nsocket = new Socket();
            nsocket.connect(sockaddr, 5000); //10 second connection timeout
            if (nsocket.isConnected()) {
                bSocketStarted = true;
                nis = nsocket.getInputStream();
                nos = nsocket.getOutputStream();
                Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Socket created, streams assigned");
                Log.i("AsyncTask", "doInBackground: Waiting for inital data...");
                int read = nis.read(buffer, 0, 4096); //This is blocking
                while(bSocketStarted) {
                    if (read > 0){
                        byte[] tempdata = new byte[read];
                        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, tempdata, 0, read);
                        publishProgress(tempdata);
                        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: Got some data");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: IOException");
            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: Exception");
            result = true;
        } finally {
            try {
                nis.close();
                nos.close();
                nsocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: Finished");
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean SendDataToNetwork(final byte[] cmd) { //You run this from the main thread.
        // Wait until socket is open and ready to use
        waitForSocketToConnect();

        if (nsocket.isConnected()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "SendDataToNetwork: Writing received message to socket");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        nos.write(cmd);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i(TAG, "SendDataToNetwork: Message send failed. Caught an exception");
                    }
                }
            }
                    ).start();
            return true;
        }
        else
            Log.i(TAG, "SendDataToNetwork: Cannot send message. Socket is closed");

        return false;
    }

    public boolean waitForSocketToConnect() {
        // immediately return if socket is already open
        if (bSocketStarted)
            return true;

        // Wait until socket is open and ready to use
        int count = 0;
        while (!bSocketStarted && count < 10000) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            count += 500;
        }

        return bSocketStarted;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values) {
        try {
            if (values.length > 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate: " + values[0].length + " bytes received.");

                String str = new String(buffer, "UTF8");
                Log.i(TAG,str);
                tv.setText(str);
                tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {}
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Cancelled.");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute: Completed with an Error.");

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute: Completed.");
        }
    }
}
```

I can instantiate the Task and call `SendDataToNetwork` from my activity. However, all the text I pass to SendDataToNetwork, for example, 'GET / HTTP/1.1' is continously sent to the server.

How can I modify my Code to maintain the connection in `doInBackground` and do nothing until I call `SendDataToNetwork` and after sending bytes to the server just wait until new data is ready to be sent? Basically I want to run the AsyncTask until I explicitly cancel (= close the connection) it.

Comment: Why do you want to leave the connection open? The user may well go through a tunnel (or if you live in the UK: take 1 step in either direction) before losing signal.

Comment: This is for some sort of telnet-like application, so you can issue raw SMTP or HTTP commands. I'd like to maintain the connection as long as the screen is active or until the user presses the disconnect button for that purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nsocket.connect(sockaddr, 5000); //10 second connection timeout
if (nsocket.isConnected()) {
```

The test is pointless. If the socket wasn't connected, `connect()` would have thrown an exception.

Your read loop is also fundamentally flawed, in that it doesn't keep reading. There are standard solutions as to how to read a stream, e.g.:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Your `waitForSocketToConnect()` method doesn't really do anything useful either.

You need to rethink all this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Changing the while loop according to your code and removing the unecessary function fixes all my issues.