# How to communicate via Socket in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, c, sockets, communication

I already have a socket communication interface which works fine in 2.3 version, but It doesn't work on 4.0.3, I've heard that it's not possible to make this kind of communication in the same thread as UI in this version so, I'm beginner in android and didn't found any example on this type of communication in 4.0.3 version, do you have some example or can tell me how to do it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can, and should, make network operations within separate Thread. See default Java Threads or AsyncTask for more information. There's plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do work on a different thread is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Be aware of the fact that your AsyncTask will break if the context gets destroyed, for example if the screen rotates. You will need to handle such events, as well.

You could read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681528/maintaining-a-tcp-connection-in-an-asynctask) and start from there.

Comment: but I want to stay with this communications running in the entire runtime of my whole program, in this situation is AsyncTask the best solution yet ?

Comment: you want to establish a connection when your app starts and keep it alive throughout the whole runtime? if that is what you're planning to do, I don't think this is necessary. why would you wanna do that?

Comment: sorry for the late, I have to keep communicating with my PLC all the way to send and receive data to keep the screen refreshing the states of the PLC.

Comment: You could try to use startService() in this case (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29). But this doesn't keep Android from killing your service if resources are low.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quote from the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) docs:

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using ICS or JB, you are restricted from opening network connections from within your main activity.  you will get an opaque error message regarding network permissions.  this is true from ICS onwards (so froyo and GB would not complain).

i cant repost my answer to another quite similar StackOverflow question here (it is considered spamming by moderators), but you can [CHECK IT OUT HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14249385/1166727).

i posted a functional send and receive socket connector client using asynctask there.